# What is the modern way to structure a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Has much changed with the release of Bundler? Is there a template that can be used as a base? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Some posts that I have found useful:

- http://chneukirchen.github.com/rps/
- http://tomayko.com/writings/require-rubygems-antipattern
- http://yehudakatz.com/2009/07/24/rubygems-good-practice/
- http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2009/9/1/gem-packaging-best-practices

**Edit** (2012-01-10): An excellent all-around guide to gem best practices is [RubyGems Guides](http://guides.rubygems.org/). I would highly recommend starting here now.

To summarize the key points:

- Use the basic `lib/gem.rb` and `lib/gem/` structure for code.
- Put any executables in `bin`, any data files in `data` and tests in `test` or `spec`.
- Don't `require` or depend upon files outside of the load path. (`VERSION` files often seem to live in odd places in gems.)
- Do not `require 'rubygems'`.
- Do not tamper with the `$LOAD_PATH`.
- If you find yourself writing `require File.join(__FILE__, 'foo', 'bar')`, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 15):

The simplest way it's to use **[bundler](http://bundler.io)**:

```
bundle gem <gem_name>
```

You may even use it in an existing project from the parent directory.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I think this is really the best way and creates a good default structure.

Answer (score 6):

This [rubygems guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/what-is-a-gem/) provides information about the structure of a gem and then goes into detail about what should be included in your [gemspec](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/)

You may find it easier to use [bundler](http://bundler.io/) to create the folder structure of the gem for you:

`bundle gem <gem_name>`

`my_gem$ bundle gem my_gem
      create  my_gem/Gemfile
      create  my_gem/Rakefile
      create  my_gem/LICENSE.txt
      create  my_gem/README.md
      create  my_gem/.gitignore
      create  my_gem/my_gem.gemspec
      create  my_gem/lib/my_gem.rb
      create  my_gem/lib/my_gem/version.rb
Initializing git repo in /Users/keith/projects/my_gem/my_gem`

Answer (score 5):

When writing fat (binary) gems the structure is usually this:

`lib/1.8/binary.so`

`lib/1.9/binary.so`

`lib/my_gem.rb` (this file simply chooses which `binary.so` to load depending on ruby version)

And for native extensions:

`lib/ext/my_gem/my_sources.*`

`lib/my_gem.rb`

I also usually put a `version.rb` file here:

`lib/my_gem/version.rb`

and it simply contains something like:

```
module MyGem
    VERSION = "0.1.0"
end
```

Also, IMO, don't put any .rb files **except** the file you want people to use to load the gem, in the `lib/` directory. Instead put all auxiliary files in `lib/my_gem/`

Answer (score 4):

Telemachus's advice is good.  If you follow it your gem will be setup to play nicely with bundler.

You might also try using jeweler.  It's a gem that generates skeletons for gems.  The default skeleton that it spits out complies with all of the conventions Telemachus mentioned and it will also do some nice things like add your favorite test framework or create a GitHub repository.

Comment: Jeweler is useful and provides a lightweight introduction to Rake as well. Thank you for this britt.