# A RubyGems with documentation, source management and API documentation?

Tags: ruby, open-source, rubygems, github

I have been wondering why so many coders have bad organization in their documents.

I think I know why.

As usual it has to do with standardization. If no standard it out there, everyone has to reinvent the wheel all the time.

So I upload a gem at RubyGems.org. But that was only 1/4 of it all.

- I have to write a tutorial for it, making categories, text style, size, color etc
- I have to generate API documentation from my code
- I have to put it in Git-hub (never done this, but that should be correct?)

It's a painful process.

Wouldn't it be great if every gem followed the same documentation structure. You upload your gem, you write a documentation for it that everyone can edit, the API documentation has been generated too, maybe created automatically, if you provided your account information for example.

A good process.

I think that would boost up good collaboration and environment than every gem has its own structure (bad documentations) and putting API documentation here and there.

Don't you agree?

Comment: Nah, github is not a requirement, but it's nice to have.

Comment: There is a draft of a standard for Ruby packaging: http://chneukirchen.github.com/rps/ You might also check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307209/what-is-the-modern-way-to-structure-a-ruby-gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of documentation (tutorial, non-generated doc, ...) is better addressed by a wiki.

Most of the public source container out there now integrates one in their features.
GitHub recently improves its [own wiki system](http://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis).
It also proposes [GitHub pages](http://pages.github.com/) (for publishing content to the web by simply pushing content to one of your GitHub hosted repositories, with user pages or project pages, and [with Jekyll](http://github.com/blog/706-jekyll-puts-on-smartypants) for even more Makdown file formats)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Would be nice if it were more of a style like that.  It's worked well for wiki's having the content changeable by the community.  I've found that gem documentation can be hit or miss sometimes.  I think having the documentation editable would be good because people could rewrite parts that are unclear making it much more user friendly

Great suggestion!