# how Do I structure/compile my ruby project

Tags: ruby, directory-structure, rakefile

im brand new to Ruby and I just finished coding a program.

the program has about 350 lines of code, 6 methods but no classes. it uses constants and global variables.

Is it convention to, for example, have the global variables/constants in a seperate file? should I split all the methods into different files?

What should the folders be like where I have all the files?

and Lastly, how do i create a makefile (or rakefile whatever it's called. i have the rake rubygem)

thank you very much

Comment: That's far to general a question and would take a whole book to cover the answers. Please be VERY VERY specific with your questions. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/ might help

Comment: Nice answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307209/what-is-the-modern-way-to-structure-a-ruby-gem

Comment: It's best to ask one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner the following would be enough.

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── app.rb
├── config.rb
└── lib/
    ├── lib1.rb
    ├── lib2.rb
```

where app.rb is you main file and you run the project using

ruby app.rb

lib/
has you library files lib1.rb and lib2.rb

suppose you are tweeting through your app then lib1.rb could be tweet.rb

Comment: ok thanks for this, but i only have 1 file right now. which is just program.rb and i run it using `ruby program.rb` in the terminal. i dont have any config or lib files. do i need to create a rakefile too or is `ruby program.rb` enough?

Comment: no you dont need a rakefile, unless you feel you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using **Hoe**: https://github.com/seattlerb/hoe

> Hoe focuses on keeping everything in its place in a useful form and
>   intelligently extracting what it needs. As a result, there are no
>   extra YAML files, config directories, ruby files, or any other
>   artifacts in your release that you wouldn't already have.

What I like is that the test directory is setup by default, and running `rake` will run the tests. I require my `lib/project_name.rb` and fill in the tests.

A Hoe setup includes a Rakefile. Rake is maintained by the same group behind Hoe, Seattle.rb. Info: https://github.com/ruby/rake; docs: http://docs.seattlerb.org/rake/

Hoe allows you to turn your project into a Gem if applicable to your use case.

Hoe has a bunch of plugins:

> Hoe has a flexible plugin system that allows you to activate and
>   deactivate what tasks are available on a given project. Hoe has been
>   broken up into plugins partially to make maintenance easier but also
>   to make it easier to turn off or replace code you don't want.

*[Plus it's written by hardcore rubyists Ryan Davis (author of MiniTest) and Eric Hodel, so the code is bulletproof and the repo stays maintained.](https://github.com/seattlerb/hoe/graphs/contributors)*

---

**Structure Overview**

```
project_dir/
  History.txt
  Manifest.txt
  README.txt
  Rakefile
  bin/...
  lib/...
  test/...
```

---

**Installation & Setup**

Install via command line:

```
gem install hoe
```

Setup a project:

```
sow project_name
```

---

**Documentation**

- http://docs.seattlerb.org/hoe/
- http://docs.seattlerb.org/hoe/Hoe.pdf

[image: Hoe Documentation PDF]

Comment: great answer, very informative. so thanks very much for that. but is all this still applicable if i only have one file (program.rb) and i run in in terminal using `ruby program.rb`? do i still need a rakefile or a lib folder/files?

Comment: It depends. What are you trying to do? If this is code for anything professional I would recommend using a directory structure with a _"rakefile or a lib folder/files"_. Check out this minimal repo to get an idea of how you could use Hoe to structure your code: https://github.com/step1profit/chef_steps

Answer (score 0):

"It uses constants and global variables." Oh, no, please, don't do this. You're making your life needlessly difficult.

You really need to avoid using global constants and variables unless you literally have no other option. They're extremely difficult to keep orderly and tend to cause chaos in any non-trivial program.

Organize everything in your program into one or more `module` or `class` definitions. Give them meaningful names. You'll use a `module` for "collection of method" containers, `class` for something that encapsulates a process or an entity of some sort.

This distinction is sometimes hard to make, but thinking about the problem carefully and trying different approaches will be necessary to do it properly.

The basics of my Ruby code are a directory called `bin/` for any sort of executables, `lib/` for the library files, `test/` for testing code, and a `README` file to explain what it all does. The last two are especially important as untested code is nothing but trouble, and undocumented code is even worse.

You'll only need a `Rakefile` if you have some kind of processes you need to perform on a routine basis. Packaging a `gem` is one such thing, or as with Rails, managing database migrations. Most projects don't need one of these, but it's sometimes helpful to include one that simply runs tests or produces documentation.

The format of a `Rakefile` is super simple, and there are literally millions of examples out there. Find one that does what you need and adapt it to your particular structure.